# connection with .csv file using ado.net and c#

Tags: c#, sql, csv, ado.net

I want to connect .csv file with windows form application using ado.net in c# language. So that I can retrieve data fro .csv file and store it in my windows form application using sql queries.
please provide me complete connection string.
thanks

Comment: Are you looking for a way to store the csv file into a database, and then the application will query this database? take a look here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30705/C-CSV-Import-Export

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing like "connection string to csv". If you want to query a CSV you can use [LINQ to CSV](http://linqtocsv.codeplex.com/) - see [some examples](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library). Then you can bind LINQ result to a e.g. DataGridView's `DataSource` property.

```
 CsvFileDescription inputFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
 {
     SeparatorChar = ',', 
     FirstLineHasColumnNames = true
 };

 CsvContext cc = new CsvContext();

 IEnumerable<Product> products =
     cc.Read<Product>("products.csv", inputFileDescription);

 // Data is now available via variable products.

 var productsByName =
     from p in products
     orderby p.Name
     select new { p.Name, p.LaunchDate, p.Price, p.Description };

 grid.DataSource = productsByName.ToList();
```